# How to export (save) data in OpenFL (Haxe) via XML(?)

Tags: haxe, openfl

In AS3 I could write the following:

```
fileReference = new FileReference();
var xmlStage:XML = new XML(<STAGE/>);
var xmlObjects:XML = new XML(<OBJECTS/>);
var j:uint;
var scene:SomeScene = ((origin_ as SecurityButton).origin as SomeScene);
var object:SomeObject;

for (j = 0; j < scene.objectArray.length; ++j) {
    object = scene.objectArray[j];
    if (1 == object.saveToXML){
        var item:String = "obj";
        var o:XML = new XML(<{item}/>);
        o.@x = scene.objectArray[j].x;
        o.@y = scene.objectArray[j].y;
        o.@n = scene.objectArray[j].name;
        o.@g = scene.objectArray[j].band;
        o.@f = scene.objectArray[j].frame;
        o.@w = scene.objectArray[j].width;
        o.@h = scene.objectArray[j].height;

        o.@s = scene.objectArray[j].sprite;
        o.@b = scene.objectArray[j].bodyType;
        xmlObjects.appendChild(o);
        //System.disposeXML(o);
    }
}

xmlStage.appendChild(xmlObjects);
fileReference.save(xmlStage, "XML.xml");
//System.disposeXML(xmlObjects);
//System.disposeXML(xmlStage);
//fileReference = null;
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Haxe? (Target of interest: **HTML5**)

If not, what are my options?

(The exported results of this code in AS3 are shown in this link below)

https://pastebin.com/raw/5twiJ01B

Comment: What is your Haxe target?

Comment: HTML5 is my primary target whilst using Haxe

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Xml class to create xml (see example: https://try.haxe.org/#68cfF )

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var root = Xml.createElement('root');
        var child = Xml.createElement('my-element');
        child.set('attribute1', 'value1'); //add your own object's values
        child.set('attribute2', 'value2'); //may be add a few more children
        root.addChild(child);

        //this could be a file write, or POST'ed to http, or socket
        trace(root.toString()); // <root><my-element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2"/></root>
    }
}
```

The `root.toString()` in that example could be instead serialized to a file File, or indeed any other kind of output (like POSTing via http to somewhere).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, although, I cannot seem to get it to work to the full extent in HTML5 export. I have a button that responds to a mouse click, that should pass the security sandbox check(s) (at least for Flash), but the dialog isn't popping up for where I would like to save the XML file on my computer (fileReference.save(root.toString(),"SomeXML.xml")), so close now, yet I feel so far away. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are running html, then what you're looking for is the html5 Blob api, and url invoking via a link. See this JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dvuyka/z8ouj1np/

Comment: Can this be used inside of a Haxe project?

Comment: yes, you can write js target specific code. http://api.haxe.org/js/html/Blob.html and http://api.haxe.org/js/html/LinkElement.html can probably get you started (and perhaps http://api.haxe.org/js/Browser.html can be of use to you too)

Answer (score 1):

You could use FileReference for flash target, and [sys.io](http://api.haxe.org/sys/io/index.html) and [File](http://api.haxe.org/sys/io/File.html) for supported targets:

```
    var output = sys.io.File.write(path, true);
    output.writeString(data);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
```